# How to move to the next/previous variable reference in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio, when working with C#, I can click on a variable, hold down `CTRL` + `SHIFT` and move between it's references using the arrow keys (up and down) inside the script that's currently open.

How can I perform such an action in VS Code while working with TypeScript?

Comment: Does my answer suffice @quickz if not let me know what I need to adjust please

Comment: @soulshined Yup, it does suffice. I didn't test the second shortcut (`F7`) initially. This one seems to function exactly the way I need. In `F3` case though, it just looks for a matching string in everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't call them references since that terminology is usually used for other things in the editor, you can use any of the following:

---

#### Scopeless

`editor.action.nextMatchFindAction` Default <kbd>F3</kbd>

`editor.action.previousMatchFindAction` Default <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

If the `findInputFocussed` criteria is met (meaning you have actively focused on the `find` input (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) you can simply use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the next match and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> for previous or you can continue to use the same <kbd>F3</kbd> bindings; they work harmoniously.

You could also just remap them to what you are using, don't have to keep it `F3`

A caveat to this approach is that your find input value must be cleared for this to work **if your word is not selected** *and* there is already an existing query *that is not the same as the word*. However, if your word *is* selected it will automatically put the word into the find input box - which is effectively the same thing as pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> when your cursor is in a word

---

#### Scope based

Similar to above, without the find/replace widget and not as many constraints, but it is limited to a 'region'.

This method cycles indefinitely and is case sensitive.

`editor.action.wordHighlight.next` Default <kbd>F7</kbd>

`editor.action.wordHighlight.prev` Default <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

---

#### Specifically for a language

You could override these to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+Navigation as you are used to if you wish, in addition to specifying the language id in the `when expression` to only work in typescript, though, it might be good to use the same keybindings across your workspaces for continuity since these keybinds are the same for other scenarios like when you are in the terminal, dealers choice though; too each their own.

Here's an example shortcut setting (you will have to put in your `keybindings.json` if you want to make a duplicate):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+down",
    "command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'typescript'"
}
```

[image]

---

#### Using symbols

Typescript supports symbols, so if you want to search based on scope you can use:

`workbench.action.gotoSymbol` Defaults <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

---

Another related way is to add the next find match to a selection using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> which adds the next found match and selects it for editing (think multiple cursors)

commandId: `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch`

Comment: In general short answer is `F7` and `SHIFT + F7`, otherwise can be used search, as you told.