# Go to previous match, after search field lost focus?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If the search field has focus, I can use Enter and Shift+Enter to go to the next/previous match.

But if the search field has lost the focus, the Enter key adds a newline to the file.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to go the next/previous match that works if the search field has lost focus?

[image: vscode-search]

Comment: search in the key bind GUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move to the next/previous variable reference in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013392/how-to-move-to-the-next-previous-variable-reference-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

if you lose focus use "F3" for next and "shift + F3" for previous